# Is this a memory leak, or normal behavior?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

While searching for memory leaks, I found a strange thing that I don't know whether it's ok or not.

In order to find memory leaks, I created a little test app with a button new and a button check doing this:

```
List<WeakReference> WeakReferences = new List<WeakReference>();

private void Button_New(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WeakReferences.Add(new WeakReference(new ObjectUnderTest()));
    // Adding a bunch of other objects to test here
}
private void Button_Check(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    int AliveCounter = 0;
    foreach (var item in WeakReferences)
    {
        if (item.IsAlive)
        {
            AliveCounter++;
            Debug.WriteLine("Object " + item.Target.GetType().ToString() + " still alive!");
        }
    }
    if (AliveCounter > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(AliveCounter.ToString() + " objects still alive!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No objects alive!");
    }
}
```

Most of my test objects get correctly garbage collected in this scenario, but there are a few objects that are still alive.

After more testing I found that these objects get indeed garbage collected, but only if I switch to another application before clicking the check button.

What do you think, is this normal behavior, or is this a memory leak, that I have to resolve?

Additional Info:
At the moment I think this is really a problem, but maybe it will not occure in our production code.

- Adding 100 objects with one click on new gives a memory exception after about 650 objetcs, so GC doesn't collect, even if the memory is needed for other purposes.
- AddMemoryPressure doesn't make anything more deterministic.
- Switching the application with mouse click doesn't help, only switching with ALT+TAB helps!?!
- Also sometimes it helps to open a new window in my test application.

Comment: If they do ultimately get collected, it can't be a "leak" - it sounds more like "I want GC to be more aggressive"

Comment: This is just a test app, because we had many leaks, mostly because of events forgotten to deregister. And in this test app, yes it would be better, if GC would be more aggressive. But for our real app I just want to know if I can be sure now, that these objects can be collected, if needed. We don't want to tell GC when to collect, we just want to be sure that they don't leak.

Our real app will be run 24/7 and so it would be a problem if it leaks.

Answer (score 5):

When `GC.Collect()` is called with no `GCCollectionMode` argument then `GCCollectionMode.Default` is used which, in most versions of the CLR, is the same as `GCCollectionMode.Forced` which forces a collection to take place. To ensure that you are forcing a collection, try calling `GC.Collect(GCCollectionMode.Forced)`.

If you still find that objects are being kept alive, this could be due to your thread racing with a concurrent collection (concurrent collection is the default in most environments) or perhaps your `ObjectUnderTest` type is self-resurrecting or has a complex reference path which is confusing the first pass of the GC (an unlikely scenario but you never know)?

On a general note, the GC will decide when is the best time to collect a given object and this behaviour is non-deterministic (unless you are calling `GC.Collect(GCCollectionMode.Forced)` or an equivalent). In some edge cases, it is necessary to influence the behavior of the garbage collector but in most cases, it's best to leave GC to do it's thing and not worry about how efficiently it's being done. This is usually efficient enough, and to make it operate *more* efficiently is likely to be quite difficult and involved.

Comment: If you are calling GC.Collect, then it is deterministic... GCCollectionMode.Default is (via MSDN) the same as GCCollectionMode.Forced, which means "Forces the garbage collection to occur immediately.". That is pretty deterministic.

Comment: It forces the garbage collection to occur immediately, but the garbage collection is still independent in its choices. So, it can decide not to free a buffer in this very moment. Or not? I think Adam intended 'non-deterministic' in this sense, like "not always doing the same stuff".

Comment: GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced) doesn't help either. The object is still alive. Only switching to another application helps. This special object I'm having trouble with is a very complicated user control generated from xaml including some grids, a canvas and Viewport3D with many 3D elements in it.

Comment: then I guess there is a rooted object somewhere in the rendering components which is keeping a strong reference to some of the objects which you are weak referencing. switching to another application means that something in your application is losing focus and this in turn makes something unrooted, which in turn unroots your objects. I guess the cause of this could be very difficult to track down, you may need to investigate the internal implementations of the rendering components.

Comment: `GCCollectionMode` is about what is collected when, not about how WeakReferences are treated.

Comment: @Henk that is true. I'm not making any claims regarding GC behaviour with regard to the WeakReference type in particular.